# UnicodeError with SqlAlchemy + Firebird + FDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, sqlalchemy

I'm triying to display results from a firebird 3.x database, but get:

> File
>   "/...../Envs/pos/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py",
>   line 479, in b2u
>       return st.decode(charset) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 9: invalid continuation byte

Despite I set utf-8 everywhere:

```
# -- coding: UTF-8 -- 

import os

os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf8"

from sqlalchemy import *

SERVIDOR = "localhost"
BASEDATOS_1 = "db.fdb"

PARAMS = dict(
    user="SYSDBA",
    pwd="masterkey",
    host="localhost",
    port=3050,
    path=BASEDATOS_1,
    charset='utf-8'
)

firebird = create_engine("firebird+fdb://%(user)s:%(pwd)s@%(host)s:%(port)d/%(path)s?charset=%(charset)s" % PARAMS, encoding=PARAMS['charset'])

def select(eng, sql):
    with eng.connect() as con:
        return eng.execute(sql)

for row in select(firebird, "SELECT * from clientes"):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: did you find a solution?
Me ajuda pelo amor de deus, to nisso a um tempo ja tambem

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
In my situation the database was not in UTF-8.
After setting the correct charset in the connection string it worked:  `?charset=ISO8859_1`

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use the module `unidecode`.

Your script is crashing when it tries to convert, so this module can help you. As they says in the module documentation:

> The module exports a single function that takes an Unicode object
>   (Python 2.x) or string (Python 3.x) and returns a string (that can be
>   encoded to ASCII bytes in Python 3.x)

First you download it using pip and then try this:

```
import unidecode

...
if type(line) is unicode:
   line = unidecode.unidecode(line)
```

I hope it solves your problem.